Why aren't all objects and their images same in size?
Suppose there is an object in front of a convex lens and we know that the light rays from each point on the surface of object will converge at a different point and form an image. So that means that the no. of points in the object and the image are EQUAL because of one to one correspondence so does that mean the size of the two MUST be same? But that just doesn't happen. Where am I wrong. Basically I am comparing infinity to infinity and I know that's not an easy task. But I want to know where my logic is wrong?

Are there more, less, or equally many points on the interval $[0,2]$ compared to $[0,1]$?

Something is infinite if the whole thing has the same number of points as just a part of it. There are the same number of even numbers as there are whole numbers. "Length of a line" is not the same as "number of points in a line".

This is an extremely poor question. What do you mean by the "number of points" in an image and why do you think it is something that can be defined? Why do you think that such a concept has anything to do with the size of the image? Note that even if you define size to be the cardinality, you can have an uncountable set with zero total physical length.

So if we cannot define what no. Of points are there why do we talk in terms of them while discussing image formation and things like that in optics? I don't understand why the question is poor it's a genuine confusion...what else should I do to understand it if I don't talk in terms of "points"?

@MariusLadegårdMeyer basically you are saying that even if the no. Of points on them is same...but lengths/size can be different?

@Peter do you mean to say that even if no. Of points on them are same the lengths can be different? It doesn't make sense intuitively but I also don't have any choice but to accept it because point is a human made concept but length is actually there and it is different and there is no doubt about it. So we have to accept that even though the no. Of points can be same in it the lengths can be different

Yes, in the sense that there is a map $y=2x$ that takes every point from the latter and gives a unique point in the former in a way where every point from each "has a partner".

But what this means is just that it does not make sense to talk about the number of point as some finite thing, and certainly not a thing that gives the size of something, image or object.

@MariusLadegårdMeyer Hmm your comment does make sense. We shouldn't related the size of something to the points because the points are dimensionless so every object will have the same no. Of points but that doesn't mean the size are equal

This might help - How An Infinite Hotel Ran Out Of Room

@VirenderBhardwaj yes you are understanding well. Regarding your earlier question why do we talk in terms of them [points] while discussing image formation and things like that in optics? This is because distances can be found between points! For instance, the height of an object is the distance from the "top point" to the "bottom point". Note that we are not counting points, we only need the two at the ends.

@MariusLadegårdMeyer I get what you are trying to say. Thanks for the insight

Dicing with infinities is usually dangerous.
Start with the idea that a small part of the object, size o$\times$o, produces an image of size i$\times$i.
Now let o become smaller and smaller.
What would happen?
i would become smaller and smaller in proportion and there is your one to one correspondence.
The problem with the word point is that mathematically a point has no spatial dimension and so a magnified point is still a point.
Thus your statement $\dots$ we know that the light rays from each point on the surface of object will converge at a different point and form an image is not really referring to a mathematical point but rather a very small area.

Can u help me understand this even with considering small areas as points. Like  if we consider that a small area converge onto a different small area in the image then still the argument will be valid right?

When the areas are finite in size the idea of magnification is valid.
